# successfully installing recovery but unable to boot into recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, fastboot, stock-rom, realme

i am facing an issue and that is i am having the current image (boot/recovery) have been destroyed and can not boot,

but I am able to boot into fastboot with power + volume buttons and i am able to flash recovery as well i have tried three recoveries twrp, orangefox, and stock and they all flash successfully but after that it again shows above mentioned message i am unable to go into recovery below is the code of my console log :)

```
platform-tools_r31.0.3-windows>adb devices
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
List of devices attached


platform-tools_r31.0.3-windows>fastboot devices
b4e38ae3        fastboot

platform-tools_r31.0.3-windows>fastboot flash recovery  orangefox.img
Sending 'recovery' (35408 KB)                      OKAY [  0.961s]
Writing 'recovery'                                 OKAY [  0.171s]
Finished. Total time: 1.181s

platform-tools_r31.0.3-windows>fastboot boot orangefox.img
Sending 'boot.img' (35408 KB)                      OKAY [  0.783s]
Booting                                            FAILED (remote: 'unknown command')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

It's a Realme 3 pro running Android 11 custom rom corvus.

I was going back to stock rom, I deleted data, cache/delvik, but not vender as it was needed i guess, and then flashed stock rom downloaded from official realme website then i flashed orangefox recovery again then magisk after that i clear cache and restart it and from there on it showing the current image(boot/recovery) have been destroyed.

Comment: its realme 3 pro the version was android 11 custom rom corvus and i was going back to stock rom, I deleted data, cache/delvik, but not vender as it was needed i guess, and then flashed stock rom downloaded from official realme website then i flashed orangefox recovery again then magisk after that i clear cache and restart it and from there on it showing the current image(boot/recovery) have been destroyed

Comment: `fastboot boot` won't boot previously flashed recovery, it will use the file given. `fastboot flash` will permanently flash file into partition, but there exist no command to boot from partition afterwards. Therefore you should press Volume Up during early boot stage, for example when typing `fastboot reboot`

Comment: anything else I could do? I did face something familiar earlier but I forget I got it to work :(

Comment: well, it`s solved what I did is I flashed a recovery then vbmeta.img and reboot it and it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

well, it`s solved what I did is I flashed a recovery then vbmeta.img and reboot it and it worked like a charm :)
fastboot --disable-verity --disable-verification flash vbmeta vbmeta.img
above is the command after flashing recovery
[link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-how-to-unlock-bootloader-install-twrp-gsi-and-magisk.3938845/) of the article I followed